# Need help in understanding parametric equation of a circle in 3D

Tags: geometry

$ = \cos  _1 + \sin  W_1$

Where V1 is a unit vector on the circle and W1 is a unit vector perpendicular to V1

I am currently working on finding an equation for a unit circle in 3D. I have come across the above equation many times but I have no idea where it actually comes from. Could someone please explain the equation to me and how it works?

Comment: what are the $V_1$ and $W_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two dimensions, a circle with radius, r, and center $C=(c_1, c_2)$  can be expressed as

$$f(t) = C + r\cos(t)\vec u + r\sin(t)\vec v$$

where $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are orthogonal unit vectors, for example$\vec u = (1,0)$ and $\vec v = (0,1)$.

To define a circle in $n$-dimensional space, the equation stays the same, except now $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are orthogonal $n$-dimensional vectors. For example, in $3$-dimensional space,

$$\text{$\vec u = \frac 17(2,3,6)$ and $\vec v = \dfrac 17(3,-6,2)$}$$

will work.

Why does this work?

If you know what the scalar product of two vectors is, then you can argue as follows

Let $P = C + r\cos(t)\vec u + r\sin(t)\vec v$ Then

\begin{align}
   \| P - C \| &= \| r(\cos(t)\vec u + \sin(t)\vec v) \| \\
   &= r^2(\cos(t)\vec u + \sin(t)\vec v)\circ(\cos(t)\vec u + \sin(t)\vec v) \\
   &= r^2(\cos^2(t) (\vec u \circ \vec u) 
      + 2 \cos(t) \sin(t) (\vec u \circ \vec v)
      + r^2(\sin^2(t) (\vec v \circ \vec v) \\
   &= r^2(\cos^2(t) \cdot 1 + 2 \cos(t) \sin(t) \cdot 0
      + r^2 \cdot \sin^2 (t) \\
    &= r^2(\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t) \\
    &= r^2
\end{align}

In words, the distance between $P$ and $C$ is $r$.

This is only true when $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ have unit lengths and are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

May I ask why must vectors u and v be orthogonal for this equation to work?

Comment: @FarmerZee It is helpful that $\|u\| = \|v\| = 1$, but that can be worked around. It is vital that $u \circ v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation before parametrization needs horizontally and vertically projected components of the tangential and normal vectors sum. This is diagonal length as shown.

[image: Circle Derivn]

Horizontal component is sum of vectors segments length $PA,AQ.$ On the right handside are the absolute values.

$$\vec{ PA} = \vec{PT} \cos t= V_1 \cos t $$

$$\vec{ AQ} = \vec{PN} \sin t=W_1 \sin t $$ by shifting short length $|PA|$ to right.

$$ V= \vec{PA}  +\vec{AQ}= V_1 \cos t+ W_1 \sin t  $$
as required. Similarly the  needed vertical component would be

$$ W =- V_1 \sin t+ W_1 \cos t  $$

EDIT1:

If a separate formula is required then spherical coordinates parametrization is useful as planarity of the circle in space is automatically taken care of.

By fixing latitude $\phi\rightarrow \phi_1$

$$ x =  R \cos \theta\cos\phi_1+h,\; y=R\sin \theta \cos \phi_1+k, \;z=R \sin \phi_1+l $$

which is a one parameter $\theta $ parametrization, where  $(h,k,l)$ are arbitrary displacements from the origin four unit circle in 3D.

Comment: Can the down-voter please indicate  how I may improve upon  my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the plane, you can write the parametric equation of a unit circle in vector form as

$$\vec p=\vec i\cos\theta +\vec j\sin\theta,$$ where $\vec i,\vec j$ are the components of the canonical base, which verify $\|\vec i\|=\|\vec j\|=1,\vec i\cdot\vec j=0$.

To get a circle in 3D space, you can apply a rotation matrix, which preserves the lengths and the angles.

$$R\vec p=R\vec i\cos\theta +R\vec j\sin\theta=\vec v\cos\theta +\vec w\sin\theta.$$

If the matrix is not orthogonal, you will get two vectors of unequal lengths or not orthogonal and the curve will be an ellipse.